# <module>...</module> vs <namespace_module>...</namespace_module> in config.xml Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configuration, best-practice

I am new into Magento development, I have created some basic modules also with the help of available tutorials. However, I am not able to understand the difference between `<module>...</module> & <namespace_module>...</namespace_module>`. Most of the time I saw in config.xml.

For example, I am creating a module `Vaibhav_Customproduct` under this module I am going to create a `Model` folder inside that `Customproduct.php` class.

Now, if I have to declare my model in config.xml I have seen in 2 different ways. I just want to understand the difference between below to declaration type.

> Example 1

```
    <models>
        <Customproduct>
            <class>Vaibhav_Customproduct_Model</class>
        </Customproduct>
    </models>
```

> Example 2

```
    <models>
        <Vaibhav_Customproduct>
            <class>Vaibhav_Customproduct_Model</class>
        </Vaibhav_Customproduct>
    </models>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference between them are `Customproduct` and `Vaibhav_Customproduct`. Those are unique identifier for your model declaration.

```
Mage::getModel('UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER/model');
```

The unique identifier which you have declared in your `config.xml` is only used to call your model.

In your case, to call your model you use below two method.

If you used unique identifier `Customproduct` then you can call your model like following

```
Mage::getModel('Customproduct/model');
```

For unique identifier `Vaibhav_Customproduct`,  you can call your model like following

```
Mage::getModel('Vaibhav_Customproduct/model');
```

From here, you can see that all model whose name begins with `Vaibhav_Customproduct_Model` are defined within Model folder of this module. Second part of `Vaibhav_Customproduct/model` OR `Customproduct/model` is telling Magento in which file is class defined. And in this case, it is `Model.php`

Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: As it is conceivable that another extensions also adds a "Customproduct" I would suggest going with the approach in Example 2 to avoid one area of possible conflict.

Comment: Thank @KristofatFooman I am following the same convention. :-)

Comment: Hey @Rohit can I have your skype id. So that, I can ask you few questions directly.

Comment: Go through my website. contact me there

Comment: @Rohit Error sending message, please try again! on your website